# Aura picklist 50 item limit

Tags: picklist, aura

The below code produces a list of 50 accounts that display in a picklist.  I need to have more items to display in the picklist.  How can I do this?  Can I change the type of picklist?

```
<lightning:select name="customField1Filter"
                  class="slds-p-horizontal--small"
                  onchange="{!c.onFilterMembers}"
                  label="{!v.pickListLabelField1}"
                  value="{!v.searchCustomField1}">
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.accountValues}" var="account">
                    <option value="{!account}">{!account}</option>
                </aura:iteration>
</lightning:select>
```

Comment: Even though you are able to populate them in a single picklist, that would be bad design from UX perspective. Have you considered using type ahead approach for showing accounts, as user types in the box?

Comment: How do you populate over 50 in a picklist?  I have the following code doing a type ahead, but I would like to populate about 60.  It stops at 50.
         lightning:input type="search"
                       class="slds-p-horizontal--small"
                       value="{!v.searchCustomField1}"
                       onchange="{!c.onSearchCustomField}"
                       name="customField1"
                       placeholder="{!v.placeHolderCustomField1}"
                       label="{!v.labelCustomField1}"/>

Comment: But why are you even doing that? Just display top 10 results and keep filtering as the user keeps typing?

Comment: Because the user might not know the way the accounts are entered in the system...for our environment a picklist will work best.  The # of them isn't going to grow much past 60.  Is there a way to show more than 50 in the dropdown picklist?

Comment: There's no known limit document about number of items in `lightning:select`. Check if your list `accountValues` consists of the right set of data that you are trying to render. Please note, I was able to add 100 values in this component and was able to display as a test.

Comment: After reviewing the code, I found that we were limiting the picklist results to 50.  I changed the limit & everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limit on the # of dropdown items was set in my org's custom code.  I corrected this and everything works.